# Windows 7 & IE9 - Search provider corruption

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Related (for Windows XP: [IE8 search provider corruption keeps forcing Bing.com upon me?](https://superuser.com/questions/33389/ie8-search-provider-corruption-keeps-forcing-bing-com-upon-me))

Windows 7, with Internet Explorer 9 and no add-ons loaded will bring up this message every time it starts:

> A program on your computer has corrupted your default search provider
>   setting for Internet Explorer.
>
> Internet Explorer has reset this setting to your original search
>   provider, Bing (www.bing.com).
>
> Internet Explorer will now open Search Settings, where you can change
>   this setting or install more search providers.

When I click OK, it brings up the *Manage Addons* page, and I can't do anything with the Search Providers. Looking at my thread about [How to Manually edit the Search Providers in Windows Internet Explorer 9](https://superuser.com/questions/399014/how-to-manually-edit-the-search-providers-in-windows-internet-explorer-9), I tried going through the registry without finding much help. Resetting IE (**Tools**->**Internet Options**->**Advanced**-><kbd>Reset</kbd>) did nothing. HiJackThis reported nothing out of the ordinary, and this occurred in Safe Mode as well.

I created a new user account, and the new account did fix it, but it is undesirable to copy all the user data over and change names. I also tried uninstalling IE9 through **Installed Updates**, but the same issue happened with IE8. What else can I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found on [this blog](http://www.cybertechhelp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=218885), it seems to be an issue with a single file. I quit Internet Explorer, navigated to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\`, and deleted the `CREDHIST` system file. After this, I went back into Internet Explorer, and the message is gone! I tried restarting the computer, and it's still gone too